# Laravel annotation for Models in PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I am creating a project based on Laravel framework and I am using PhpStorm for it. By default, Laravel has the following settings if we enable Laravel plugin in PhpStorm.

[image: PhpStorm Settings]

Now based on these settings if I create a model and try to define all the relations and other properties in the following way

```
<?php
  /**
   * Class User
   *
   * @package App\Http\Entities
   * @property int $id
   * @property mixed $posts
   */
  class User extends Model
  {

      /**
       * The table associated with the model
       *
       * @var string
       */
      protected $table = 'users';

     /**
      * Indicates if model should be timestampped
      *
      * @var bool
      */
      public $timestamps = false;

     /**
      * The attributes are not mass assignable
      *
      * @var array
      */
     protected $guarded = ['type'];

    /**
     * Get all the posts for a user
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function posts()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Entities\Post');
    }

}
```

Automatically I have to add all the annotations for the class or warning is shown by PhpStorm which is obviously because settings are enabled if I disabled them warnings are gone as well.

But I am curious to know what do they actually represent as it must have some reason if it was set by default. Also when writing other models I noticed that when I defined a function inside a model like this

```
public function userComments()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Some model');
}
```

In annotation, it gets set to something like this

```
/**
 * @property $user_comments
 */
```

Now firstly it was a function and also for above cases where I defined a function post(), the annotation was set as **@property** which is again confusing to me. Secondly, I like to define my variable as well as function to **camelCase** but because of all this annotation getting set at top of the class 
as snake_case I somehow don't like that.

So all I want to know is what are they basically and what is the purpose of defining them and what do they represent.

P.S. This is my very first project with Laravel framework and I know that it has to do with PHP Documentation and everything but I have never really documented my code earlier. So any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: *"has the following settings if we enable Laravel plugin in PhpStorm"* It's not **Laravel Plugin**. It's **Laravel Insight**, which is different thing (I personally have removed it as it does not provide much useful stuff for me .. at least since I'm already familiar with Laravel)

Comment: *"So all I want to know is what are they basically and what is the purpose of defining them and what do they represent."* 1) https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#714-property 2) When you will be accessing `id` or another field of your model,  you will use `$model->id`. Well: there is no real `id` field anywhere. Instead Laravel redirects it to `$model->attributes['id']` IIRC. Declaring them via `@property` tells IDE that `id` field exists (one way or another) so it should not mark them as unknown; plus, IDE will offer such fields in auto-completion.

Comment: About snake_case vs cameCase. I always use exactly the same spelling as the field declared in DB. But if you wish and it works fine for you -- use camelCase. But then it's up to that plugin (how it can be configured) to recognize it (not to generate false warnings).

Comment: @LazyOne  that's the thing as soon as i change it to camelCase it no longer recognize that function guess its not configurable